# Concatenating two existing columns within a new query

Tags: postgresql

I have this query below that parses names within columns based on specific criteria. I would like to augment this query in order to contain a new row that will include a concatenation of two columns from the mk_kw table.

```
insert into mk_kw
with a(v) as (
select "Campaign"
from adwords_raw
), pre as (
select split_part(v, '{', 1) a,split_part(v, '{', 2) b
from a)
select
split_part(a, '-', 1) ca,
split_part(a, '-', 2) cb,
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) cc,
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3),
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) || '|', 2) cd,
'{' || b ce
from pre;
```

The current input table looks like the following,  "Campaign" being the current column in action

```
Campaign                           |Adgroup |
-----------------------------------+--------+
ES-SRC-IOT|Connectivity|SIM|USA|{e}|Watches |
```

The current output of this looks like the following

```
 ca | cb  |    cc     |             cd             |  ce
----+-----+-----------+----------------------------+------
 ES | SRC | IOT       |  Connectivity | SIM | USA  | {e}
```

I would like to add a concatenation in this formula that would create this as an output

```
 ca|cb |cc |cd                  |ce |Campaign&AdGroup
---+---+---+--------------------+---+------------------------------
 ES|SRC|IOT|Connectivity|SIM|USA|{e}|ES-SRC-IOT|Connectivity|SIM|USA 
   |   |   |                    |   |{e}Watches
```

Is it possible to add this concatenation or would I have to scrap this query entirely?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into mk_kw
with a(v,a) as (
select "Campaign","Adgroup"
from adwords_raw
), pre as (
select split_part(v, '{', 1) a,split_part(v, '{', 2) b,v||a as Campaign&AdGroup
from a)
select
split_part(a, '-', 1) ca,
split_part(a, '-', 2) cb,
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) cc,
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3),
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) || '|', 2) cd,
'{' || b ce,
Campaign&AdGroup
from pre;
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need concat, just reuse existing columns:

```
with a(v,g) as (
select "Campaign","Adgroup"
from adwords_raw
), pre as (
select split_part(v, '{', 1) a,split_part(v, '{', 2) b,v||g "Campaign&AdGroup"
from a
)
select
split_part(a, '-', 1) ca,
split_part(a, '-', 2) cb,
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) cc,
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3),
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) || '|', 2) cd,
'{' || b ce,
"Campaign&AdGroup"
from pre;
```

Comment: Thanks again Vao.

Comment: Hello Vao, What if I would like to add three columns instead to this?  As an example "Campaign","Ad group","Week".  I have tried to insert this according to the same logic to no avail.